# How can we create an instance of Backbone view using the string name store in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, constructor, backbone-views

I'm creating a visual builder using different view for each component. All the view are declared like below:

```
$(function() {
   var parallaxView = new Backbone.view.extend({
        ....
   });
   var parallaxView = new Backbone.view.extend({
        ....
   }); 
});
```

At one point i start to create a new object view from that view. But all i know is the string represent the name of the view store in an object

```
name
```

My question can we create an object in some way such as new class using that object value as class name.

```
var myView = new name(param1, param2);
```

instead of using

```
switch (name) {
   case 1:
      ....
}
```

I have try this case

```
var myView = new name(param1, param2);
```

and i know that it won't wok. But is there any way to can create an object in someway like that?

Comment: What is your objective? And what is param1, param2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question in a right way, you can store views constructors in object like this:

```
$(function() {
    window.views = {
        'parallax': Backbone.View.extend({ /*...*/ }),
        'test': Backbone.View.extend({ /*...*/ })
    };
});
```

Then you can create instances this way:

```
// var name = 'parallax';
var myView = new window.views[name](param1, param2);
```

Please let me know if your problem is not like I understand it.